# How to select radio button in selenium webdriver?

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I am new to selenium webdriver. I'm writing script using java but I got stuck in writing script, I want to select a radio button but I'm getting

> Exception in thread "main"
>   org.openqa.selenium.ElementNotVisibleException: Element is not
>   displayed (WARNING: The server did not provide any stacktrace
>   information) error.

This is I have written:

```
WebElement radioButton = driver.findElement(By.id("Radio_0_2461A"));
radioButton.sendKeys(Keys.SPACE);
```

Below is HTML code:

```
HTML code for Find button.

<button class="button right secondary" id="selectProducts0" onclick="getProducts('0'); return false;">
        Find Products
    </button>
```

Once button clicked product will load and I have to select product from list.

```
    <div class="clearboth" id="productList0" style="overflow: hidden; display: block;">
    <div class="productTableContainer" data-index="0">

 <table class="responsive" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" summary="List of products">
   <tbody>            
    <tr data-row-data='{"earlyRepaymentCharges":[],"incentives":[]}'>
    <th class="radio">
    <input id="0_2689A_StartDate" type="hidden" value="28/06/2016 00:00:01">
    <input name="Products[0].ProductCode" title="Lifetime Tracker with £999 Fee" id="Radio_0_2689A" type="radio" value="2689A"> <label for="Radio_0_2689A">
     Lifetime Tracker with £999 Fee </label>

<tr data-row-data='{"earlyRepaymentCharges":[{"step":"1","durationInMonths":"","endDate":"30/11/2016","percentage":"1%"}],"incentives":[]}'>
    <th class="radio">
   <input id="0_5555A_StartDate" type="hidden" value="01/11/2015 00:01:00">
   <input name="Products[0].ProductCode" title="1 Year Fixed Rate Until 30/11/2016 with £999 Fee" id="Radio_0_5555A" type="radio" value="5555A">
 <label for="Radio_0_5555A"> 1 Year Fixed Rate Until 30/11/2016 with £999 Fee
 </label>

<tr data-row-data='{"earlyRepaymentCharges":[{"step":"1","durationInMonths":"","endDate":"28/02/2017","percentage":"2%"},{"step":"2","durationInMonths":"","endDate":"28/02/2018","percentage":"1%"}],"incentives":[]}'>
 <th class="radio">
<input id="0_2461A_StartDate" type="hidden" value="18/12/2015 00:01:00">                          
<input name="Products[0].ProductCode" title="2 Year Fixed Rate Until 28/02/2018 with £999 Fee" id="Radio_0_2461A" type="radio" value="2461A">
 <label for="Radio_0_2461A">2 Year Fixed Rate Until 28/02/2018 with £999 Fee
</label>
```

Comment: Please post your code in the question itself rather than link us to it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think radio button I'd is dynamically generated. Try using `By.name()` with `WebDriverWait` to wait until radio button visible as below :-

```
WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver,10);
WebElement radio = wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.name("Products[0].ProductCode")));
radio.click();
```

**Edited1** :- If you radio button id is fixed then try using `By.id` with `WebDriverWait` to wait until radio button visible as below :-

```
WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver,10);
WebElement radio = wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.id("Radio_0_2461A")));
radio.click();
```

**Edited2**:- If you can find radio button but not selecting due to visibility, you can try using `JavascriptExecutor` to select the radio as below :-

```
WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver,10);
WebElement radio = wait.until(ExpectedConditions.presenceOfElementLocated(By.id("Radio_0_2461A")));
((JavascriptExecutor)driver).executeScript("arguments[0].click()", radio);
```

**Edited3**:- if unfortunately javascript click does not work on radio button try using `Javascript` `Mouse` event to perform click as below :-

```
WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver,10);
WebElement radio = wait.until(ExpectedConditions.presenceOfElementLocated(By.id("Radio_0_2461A")));
((JavascriptExecutor)driver).executeScript("var clickEvent = document.createEvent('MouseEvents');clickEvent.initEvent ('click', true, true);arguments[0].dispatchEvent (clickEvent);", radio);
```

Hope it helps...:)

Comment: @PrashantBellale and what about I'd?? It's dynamically changed or fixed??

Comment: I think ID is fixed, I tried with ID but still it is not selection radio button. actual scenario is I have click on find product button then wait till product load, once product loaded then select product. I'll answer with all code, it will help to understand.

Comment: @PrashantBellale try `By.id("Radio_0_2461A")`. if id is fixed using `WebDriverWait` to wait until it's visible and let me know the result..:)

Comment: I'm geting Exception in thread "main" org.openqa.selenium.TimeoutException: Timed out after 30 seconds waiting for visibility of element located by By.id: Radio_0_2461A. I tried with 10 second and then I changed to 30 second.

Comment: @PrashantBellale Ok i think there are some issue by visibility, may be due designing issues..I provided you to select radio using `JavascriptExecutor`..try second updated..Hope it works..:)

Comment: I have tried with 'JavascriptExecutor', product is highlighted.  Looks like it is selecting product but not clicking on radio button.

Comment: @PrashantBellale may be radio button wants mouse event then you should use `edited3` where click will perform using `Javascript` `MouseEvent`..try with latest updated answer and let me know..:)

Comment: I have tried with `JavaScript` `MouseEvent` result is same. product is highlighted but not clicked on radio button.

Comment: @PrashantBellale Make sure provided Id is unique and assigned only to radio button

Comment: @PrashantBellale To make sure Print `Syetem.out.println(radio.getAttribute("type"))` and see result that it printed radio or something else

Comment: I tried System.out.println(radio.getAttribute("type")) and result printed radio.

Comment: Thanks Saurabh. It is working now. I have used By.id("0_2461A_StartDate")`.